# woocommerce search only parent category products based on body class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the code below but am not sure how to add in two separate search forms that search for products ONLY in the parent category. Either `product_parent_cat_floral` or `product_parent_cat_rentals`

```
            <?php
                $classes = get_body_class();
                if (in_array('product_parent_cat_rentals',$classes)) {
            ?>

                //rentals search form would go here

            <?php } else { ?>

                //flowers search form would go here

            <?php } ?>
```

Can I edit this search form to somehow make it only search for products within the appropiate parent class?

```
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://botanicaevents.com/rentals/">
        <div>
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search for products" />
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_cat" value="rentals" />
```

so your search query becomes:

```
?s=some+search+string&post_type=product&product_cat=rentals
```

to additionally restrict the search within the `rentals` product category.